# How would I resolve this object serialization error in UE5?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am currently working on an UnrealEngine 5 project and have run into an issue. The project works perfectly fine in the editor and the only warning I see during the packaging process are:

```
“VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/SQLiteExt”, “VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/InterchangeFactoryNodes”, and
“VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/InterchangePipelines”
```

After the packaging process is complete though, the game instantly crashes upon loading after opening the exe file, here's the error text:

```
LowLevelFatalError

[File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Serialization\AsyncLoading2.cpp] [Line: 1568]

ObjectSerializationError:
/Game/FirstPerson/Blueprints/BP_FirstPersonCharacter
(0x4FF1CD82686CA948)

/Game/FirstPerson/Blueprints/BP_FirstPersonCharacter
(0x4FF1CD82886CA948) - BP_FirstPersonCharacter_C

/Game/FirstPerson/Blueprints/BP FirstPersonCharacter.Default__BP_FirstPersonCharacter_C:
Bad export index 67108863/25.
```

And the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfVJA.png).

Are the warnings in any way related to the crash?
If they are how do I fix this?
If they aren't then what is it and how do I fix that?

I've been trying to find more information online but so far haven't found anything useful about this issue. The few things I have found either didn't work or were not related.

Edit: Added part of the error log that I assume will be useful here.
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trasQ.png)

Comment: What do the logs says?

Comment: added error log image

Comment: What do you get when you run it in debug mode

Comment: This might be a ram issue. This right here: "fatal error:[ File:D:\build\++UES\Sync\Engine\Source\RunTime\CoreUObject\Private\Serialization\AsyncLoading2.cpp ] [line: 1568]" is responsible for loading and unloading of assets and can act up if it does not have the correct resources. You could also try to rerun it without that firstpersoncharacter and see if it runs. If it does then you have found your problem.

Comment: Assuming it's a ram issue, how would I fix that?

Comment: That's easy just go to getmorreram (THAT'S A JOKE DON'T DO THAT). If you think that your computer is powerful enough then you can dedicate unused ram to Unity. If Not then you should look into upgrading your computer's memory modules

Comment: @CupOfJava is right, Unreal Engine 5 is notoriously known for its high usage of computer resources. Unreal Engine requires **at least** [8 GB of ram](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/hardware-and-software-specifications-for-unreal-engine/) if not more to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same messsage:

```
“VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/SQLiteExt”, “VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/InterchangeFactoryNodes”
```

and

```
“VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/InterchangePipelines”
```

And project not opening anymore. I had the problem on notebook and was thinking about performance, today I tested on another machine and nothing related to ram hdd, etc  etc.

Solved with a workaround!

Thanks to Git, I branched the commit before and it was working, so definitevely some problem of serialization of corruption. Cherry picked files one-by-one I found my implementation of PlayerController being the guilty file of.... no idea.

```
"“VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/SQLiteExt”, “VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/InterchangeFactoryNodes”
```

and

```
“VerifyImport: Failed to find script package for import object 'Package /Script/InterchangePipelines”"
```

This is a false log in my opinion, very misleading =')

I got this error while opening the project, so slightly different by your case, but that log is related on something else (spotted also other occurence in the building log), in my cases the engine probably is stucked in a loop caused by something wrong wrote in blueprint that for some reason has not been spotted by the BP compiler, this error is saved in the uasset and when going to read now can't proceed.
My 2 cent.

The file probably can be considered corrupted and the changes lost.

In your cases can be dependent from something that change between editor e packaging, maybe you want add into `Config/DefaultEngine.ini` the row:

```
[Core.log]
AssetLog = VeryVerbose
```

`Assetlog` is a `logcategory`, so you have to search in the code other log categories that can be related. E.G:

```
LogStreaming
LogMaterial
```

Etc, etc.